# Java 2D Array sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, 2d

I'm working on an assignment for college, I'm struggling to figure out why specifically this line wont work

```
return Full_Name.compareTo(Age, Student_ID, Comm_Marks, Work_Exp_Marks,Mathematics_Marks);
```

I've tried messing around with it, quick Google search for the error fix but nothing came up (well... for me at least)

What I need to do is to organize the array in alphabetical order then the other array values to follow the values it was beside originally. So, for example when the Full_Name array is sorted in alphabetical order and Bruce Wayne is sorted in this then the Student_ID  of, "RP0023" must follow Bruce Wayne around along with the Age array and the marks for subjects...if that makes sense, there's more steps after but this is the hardest part of the assignment that needs to be done. I've been struggling with this problem for a week now. The lecturer suggested to use the Compare To function for the sorting so that's what I've been trying to do.

I really want to get this sorting over with as quickly as possible so I can move on with the assignment because I can't continue without doing the sorting. Hopefully I covered everything I need to and make sense. Also I'm writing the code and making sure it works before making it print in a readable manner in the console.

```
package javaapplicationtest;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class JavaApplicationTest 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Integer[] proxyLookup = new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    String[][] Full_Name 
            = {
                {"Bruce Wayne", "Dinah Lance", "Celina Kyle", "Clark Kent"},
                {"Barry Allen", "Barbara Gordon", "Hal Jordon", "Ray Palmer"}
            };

    int[][] Age = {
     {18, 19, 23, 34},
      {19, 16, 24, 37}
    };

     String[][] Student_ID 
             = {
                 { "RP0023", "RP0024", "RP0025", "RP0026"},
                 {"RP0027", "RP0028", "RP0029", "RP0030"}
             };    

      Double[][] Comm_Marks 
              = {
                {87.4, 67.8, 45.3, 14.5} ,
                {76.8, 54.2, 56.3, 98.2}
      };

      Double[][] Work_Exp_Marks 
              = {
                  {67.5, 72.6, 97.5, 76.2} ,
                  {83.0, 45.5, 37.1, 87.4}
              };

       Double[][] Mathematics_Marks 
               = {
                   {92.4, 54.3, 56.3, 67.3} , 
                   {23.4, 67.4, 84.4, 90.0}
               };    

    System.out.println("Unsorted Array:  \n ==============");
    for (int index : proxyLookup) 
    {
        System.out.println(Full_Name[index] + ";" + Age[index] + ";" + Student_ID[index]);
    }

      Arrays.sort(proxyLookup, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return Full_Name.compareTo(Age, Student_ID, Comm_Marks, Work_Exp_Marks,Mathematics_Marks);

        }
    });


     System.out.println("Sorted Aray: \n ==============");

    for (int index : proxyLookup) {
        System.out.println(Full_Name[index] + "; " + Age[index] + "; " + Student_ID[index]);
    }



}



  }
```

Comment: Hi there! I'm not sure what you are asking. Stack Overflow is not a good place to get open-ended help debugging your code. You will do better here by asking specific questions. After reading yours three times, I am still not able to understand what you are trying to do. It appears you want us to do your homework.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I'll update the description and my problem is with this line ( return Full_Name.compareTo(Age, Student_ID, Comm_Marks, Work_Exp_Marks,Mathematics_Marks); ) because it's giving me an error on compareTo and I don't know why it's giving me an error. I've messed around with different ways of doing it and still giving me the error however when I use it for a single array it works perfectly... I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I don't want people to do my work for me, I'm just confused by the error and I added all the code in case one part is causing errors for it

Comment: You haven't even told us what the error is. Usually the error tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I'm just in a rush to find a solution so I can work on the rest myself for the assignment and hand it up by Friday so I'm sorry for the lack of detail to my question and if there's errors in my wording, spellings, grammar etc

Comment: Full_Name.compareTo doesn't exist as far as i can see.

Comment: Well it's saying it cannot find symbol but the code works grand when I used it for a single 2D array structure and it's highlighted the compareTo with red.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your lecturer suggested represent such students as class instances and then use `compareTo` to compare them?
like

```
public class Student {
    private String fullName;
    private int age;
    private String studentId;
    private double commMarks;
    private double workExpMarks;
    private double mathematicsMarks;

    public Student(String fullName, int age, String studentId, double commMarks, double workExpMarks, double mathematicMarks) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age = age;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.commMarks = commMarks;
        this.workExpMarks = workExpMarks;
        this.mathematicsMarks = mathematicMarks;
    }...getters and setters omitted...
}

class Calculations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student("Bruce Wayne", 18, "RP0023", 87.4, 67.5, 92.4);
        Student s2 = new Student("Dinah Lance", 19, "RP0024", 67.8, 72.6, 54.3);
        ...etc...

        Student[] proxyLookup = new Student[]{s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8};
        Arrays.sort(proxyLookup, (o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName()) != 0)) {
                return o1.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName());
            }
            if (o1.getStudentId().compareTo(o2.getStudentId()) != 0)){
                return o1.getStudentId().compareTo(o2.getStudentId());
            }
...etc... 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and no he wasn't asking about comparing different arrays but rather maybe using the compare to for sorting the array (a-z) which I've been struggling with so I started it all from scratch and I'm trying to use a method that seems to work on single dimensional array but not on 2d array. I'm new to learning Java so I'm struggling to get this done plus I'm very stressed about it so forgive me about all of this with confusion and all.